Drop all duplicates in the dataframe if a row contains value greater than X in one column
I would like to clean my dataframe:
A   B     C...(other columns)
1   100
1   98
2   150
2   100 #(removed)
2   90 #(removed)
3   200
3   75 #(removed)
4   80
4   80
4   70
4   70

.. so that the duplicated rows by "A" are removed if there is a value higher than 100 in "B". So the output should be:
A   B    C...(other columns)
1   100
1   98
2   150
3   200
4   80
4   80
4   70
4   70

Bear in mind that column A not necessarily will be contain digits.
I thought maybe using sort_values with >100 but some have nan values and doesn't work properly.

code of minimal and reproducible example
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
         'B': [100, 98, 150, 100, 90, 200, 75, 80, 80, 70, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)


Code
cond1 = ~df['A'].duplicated()
cond2 = df['B'].le(100).groupby(df['A']).transform('all')
out = df[cond1 | cond2]

out:
    A   B
0   1   100
1   1   98
2   2   150
5   3   200
7   4   80
8   4   80
9   4   70
10  4   70


Filter all rows with maximal values less like 100 per groups by GroupBy.transform and also first duplicated value per A by Series.duplicated:
out = df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max').le(100) | ~df['A'].duplicated()]
print (out )
    A    B
0   1  100
1   1   98
2   2  150
5   3  200
7   4   80
8   4   80
9   4   70
10  4   70

How it working:
print (df.assign(max=df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max'),
                 le100 = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max').le(100),
                 dup = ~df['A'].duplicated(),
                 both = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max').le(100) |
                         ~df['A'].duplicated()))

    A    B  max  le100    dup   both
0   1  100  100   True   True   True
1   1   98  100   True  False   True
2   2  150  150  False   True   True
3   2  100  150  False  False  False
4   2   90  150  False  False  False
5   3  200  200  False   True   True
6   3   75  200  False  False  False
7   4   80   80   True   True   True
8   4   80   80   True  False   True
9   4   70   80   True  False   True
10  4   70   80   True  False   True

Or use Series.isin for get all A groups without greater values in B by 100:
out = df[~df['A'].isin(df.loc[df.B.gt(100),'A']) | ~df['A'].duplicated()]
print (out)
    A    B
0   1  100
1   1   98
2   2  150
5   3  200
7   4   80
8   4   80
9   4   70
10  4   70

How it working:
print (df.assign(gt100=df.B.gt(100),
                 per_groups=~df['A'].isin(df.loc[df.B.gt(100),'A']),
                 dup = ~df['A'].duplicated(),
                 both = ~df['A'].isin(df.loc[df.B.gt(100),'A']) |
                 ~df['A'].duplicated()))

    A    B  gt100  per_groups    dup   both
0   1  100  False        True   True   True
1   1   98  False        True  False   True
2   2  150   True       False   True   True
3   2  100  False       False  False  False
4   2   90  False       False  False  False
5   3  200   True       False   True   True
6   3   75  False       False  False  False
7   4   80  False        True   True   True
8   4   80  False        True  False   True
9   4   70  False        True  False   True
10  4   70  False        True  False   True

